# Xcode C++ and folders structure

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

Is possible force Xcode to create folder, instead only some logical group? I need to do project and have some folder structure, like NET classes in net folder, etc., so then including header files and writing makefile must be compatible with this structure.I don't know how to create real folder in xcode. It creates only some logical groups and sources are in one physical folder, so for example two files, names Connection, can't coexists, even if their classes are in different namespace and they should be in different folders("packages").

Answer (score 1):

Right click, "Add files...", click "New Folder", and select the folder. Will this work for your needs?
Alternatively, just create the folder in the finder and drag it into the source list.

Either way, just make sure you click "Create folder references for any added folders" rather than "Create groups for any added folders".